# I need help with Steinberg ur22 interface on Mint Linux

Tags: recording, software

I have a Steinberg ur22 mk2, but they do not support it on Mint Linux. Where can I find compatible drivers?

Comment: I have read that the UR22 MkII us class compliant. This should mean the generic USB driver is compatible.

Comment: alsa driver installed but still no show steinberg still off no support for linux? does the driver have a name regards al